# Getting directory path of the master executable .jar file

Tags: java

In debugging I found that my current way of storing a database's files (`embedded derby database`) didn't work when running the executable `.jar` file that's compiled by `NetBeans 8.0`.

Simply put, I need a way of getting the application to find the directory the `.jar`file is being run from, and to set up the `embedded DB database` in the same directory.

In case it helps, the current way I get it to 'work' (within the IDE) is as follows:

```
public final void setDBSystemDir() throws UnsupportedEncodingException, SQLException{
        String path = DataBase.class.getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation().getPath();
        String decodedPath = URLDecoder.decode(path, "UTF-8");
        String systemDir = decodedPath + "/listData/";
        System.setProperty("derby.system.home", systemDir);
}
```

Any pointers welcome.

Comment: Did you read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/320542/how-to-get-the-path-of-a-running-jar-file?rq=1?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code to get the path,

```
CodeSource source = DataBase.class.getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource();
File file = new File(source.getLocation().toURI().getPath());
String dir = file.getParentFile().getPath();
```